# Laravel 5.4 - Sending mail in a loop

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4

I would like to send mail to several person using `Laravel 5.4`

```
foreach($company->getAllAdministrators() as $admin){
    Mail::to($admin->email)->send($email);
}
```

#### Problem

The first email would be `to : admin1@mail.com`

The second email would be `to : admin1@mail.com` `admin2@mail.com`

#### Question

What is the right way to send the email to all recipients without adding them in the `to`. I do not want a admin to be able to see other recipients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `getAllAdministrators()` method is returning `Users` you can use the `bcc` method on the `Mail` class. The `bcc` method accepts an email address, a user instance, *or a collection of users*. For example:

```
Mail::to('admins@mydomain.com')
    ->bcc($company->getAllAdministrators())
    ->send($email);
```

Where `admins@mydomain.com` is simply a generic email address of your choice (it's also a good way to confirm delivery on your end).